# Create another column and add a label to it

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working with SPSS files where each column name (variable) has a label.

I want to create another column using mutate and add a label to keep it consistent with other columns.

Below is an example - add two column `sum` (a + b + c) and `mean`. Add label a label "Sum of all", "Mean of all"

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjlabelled)

# Set variable labels for data frame
dummy <- tibble(a = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    b = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    c = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  set_label(c("Variable A", "Variable B", "Variable C"))


# add another columns sum and mean. Add label a label "Sum of all" , "Mean of all"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, we get the `rowSums` by selecting `across` all the columns (`everything()`) in the data to create the 'Sum', then do the same except the `Sum` (`-Sum`) to get the row wise mean (`rowMeans`) and use `set_label` to create a named vector by concatenating the already existing labels (`get_label`) from the data with the new labels

```
library(sjlabelled)
library(dplyr)
dummy <- dummy %>%
   mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(everything())), 
          Mean = rowMeans(across(c(everything(), -Sum)))) %>%
    set_label(c(get_label(dummy), "Sum" = "Sum of all", "Mean" = "Mean of all" ))
```

-checking

```
> get_label(dummy)
            a             b             c           Sum          Mean 
 "Variable A"  "Variable B"  "Variable C"  "Sum of all" "Mean of all"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also tell how to do if there multiple columns. I have modified question slightly.

Comment: @SiH Does the update helps you

Comment: Thanks can you suggest any book to efficiently work on SPSS data using R. I was told R is good for analysis but not good for data management, so stick to SPSS. Since this is a subjective question. It will voted down if I ask separately

Comment: @SiH sorry, I am not very sure about the SPSS data extraction with R

Comment: okayu no problem